# Is there any problem with this statement?

Tags: sentence-construction, present-continuous

I have been studying some differences between Present Perfect and Present Perfect Continuous and, recently, I came across with this statement:

> I have been running 10 km.

As far as I'm concerned, so that this sentence to become right, we need to remove the term "10 km". Am I right?

Comment: It depends on context, but I would understand that sentence to mean "I have been in the habit of running 10km recently". In that sense, it is perfectly normal. If they are referring to a single run, then it is odd.

Answer (score 1):

I picture a conversation like this:

A: "I've been running every week to keep fit."
B: "What distance have you been running?"
A: "I've been running 10 km."

There's nothing wrong with the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on context really.

In isolation I'd interpret it as 'I've recently run 10km' or 'I've just run 10km'.

It may mean 'I have been running 10 km (regularly)'. In which case it's better to add regularly.